# Why does exec open a file instead of execute it?

Tags: php

I have this exec:

```
exec('start /B index.php r');
```

When I run it on localhost it opens the `index.php` file in Visual Studio Code.

The same happens when I use this:

```
pclose(popen('start /B index.php r'));
```

How can I make it so that exec executes it instead of opening it?

This is on Windows.

Comment: Windows does not support the shebang or binfmt_misc. You have to specify an interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a file to the `start` command on Windows, it opens that file in whatever is the default application to handle it. On your system, apparently, that is set to be Visual Studio Code for PHP files.

If you want to *execute* it using the PHP interpreter, you have two options:

1. Configure your Windows installation to open .php files with the PHP interpreter (this will mean you can no longer double-click a PHP file and have it open in VSCode)
2. Don't `start` the PHP file, but `start` the PHP interpreter.

The second option is probably preferable. You can use `start /B C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f index.php r` (that's where the PHP interpreter is on my machine, you might need to replace it with a different path if you have it somewhere else).

Comment: I figured it was something like that, is there a way to automate it on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: On Linux, you'd have to execute `/usr/bin/php -f index.php r` (without `start /B`). You can check the `PHP_OS` constant to determine which command to execute. On my Ubuntu machine it is set to `Linux`, on my Windows 10 box it is `WINNT`.

Comment: How do I go about passing parameters with the file using your method?

Comment: You place them at the end. The `r` at the end is a parameter.

Comment: What I mean is for example a username and an file extension.

Comment: You can supply them in the same manner as you already supply the `"r"` parameter in your original question. Say you have a `$username = "Bob";` in your application, you can then `exec("start /B C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f index.php r $username ext")`. This will populate `$argv` such that `$argv[0]` is `"index.php"`, `$argv[1]` is `"r"`, `$argv[2]` is `"Bob"` and `$argv[3]` is `"ext"`. If your `$username` can contain special characters, [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) might be required.